# Test if an object is an Enum

Tags: c#, enums, value-type

I would like to know if 'theObject' is an enum (of any enum type)

```
 foreach (var item in Enum.GetValues(theObject.GetType())) {

     //do something
 }
```

Answer (score 231, accepted):

The question is the answer. :)

```
bool isEnum = theObject is Enum;
```

Comment: Love it! And even closer to the question: if (theObject is Enum) {...}

Comment: This isn't even what I came here for and I'm giving you a point. It's so... clean... <sniff>, it's beautiful man T.T

Comment: /*Test*/ if (anObject is /*an*/ Enum) {}

Comment: bool isEnum = theObject.GetType().IsEnum; is better, is Enum doesn't always return true

Comment: @chrishu could you specify in which cases this answer would not work? Otherwise this comment is not helping

Answer (score 76):

If you have a `Type`, use the [`Type.IsEnum`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.isenum) property, e.g.:

```
bool isEnum = theObject.GetType().IsEnum;
```

Comment: This worked for me. I couldn't figure out how to make the accepted answer work in VB.NET.

Comment: I actually needed to know how to check for a `Type` being an Enum type. +1

Answer (score 10):

just use

```
if (theObject is Enum)
 //is an enum
```

Answer (score 6):

For generic type parameters, the parameter can be constrained rather than tested:

```
where T : Enum
```

Comment: C# 7.3! that's a really good reason to update C# version :) project properties->build->Advanced