# X is enum - is this according to spec?

Tags: c#, enums, language-implementation

[Test if an object is an Enum](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2918800/822637) discusses testing an object with `is Enum` to see if it contains an enum value.

Is this specified anywhere in the spec? The entry on `is` (7.10.10 in Version 4.0) lists the following possible right-hand values:

- anonymous function
- method group
- null
- reference type ** This might be an enum?
- nullable type
- non-nullable value type ** This might be an enum?

Assuming that an enum value matches "reference type" from the list above - the spec states as follows:

> ...the result is true if D [the dynamic type of the RHS)] and T [the LHS] are the same type, if D is a reference type and an implicit reference conversion from D to T exists, or if D is a value type and a boxing conversion from D to T exists.

Are any of these conditions strictly true in the case of `is Enum`? There is no compiler support for, say, `is class` or `is struct`.

So is the support for `is Enum` according to the specification, or is it an implementation decision?

Comment: What makes you think an enum **value** is a **reference** type?

Comment: @BoltClock: Because the code says so! `typeof(Enum).IsValueType => false`

Comment: Are you specifically asking about the `Enum` type or user defined enums? There seems to be a bit of confusion (including me ;p)

Comment: How would you have an instance of `Enum`? It's more or less an abstract class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no support for `is class` or `is struct`, because there is no common base type that would differentiate classes or structs from other types. `is Enum` works, because [`System.Enum`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.aspx) is an actual type that is the base of all enums. And `Enum` is a reference type, so the last part applies:

> if D is a value type and a boxing conversion from D to T exists

`D` (the type of the expression on the left side) is a value type. And `T` is `Enum`, which is a base type of `D`. So there is a boxing conversion from `D` to `Enum` and so the value of the expression is `true`.

The boxing conversion from any enum to `Enum` is specified explicitly in §14.4 The System.Enum type:

> The type `System.Enum` is the abstract base class of all enum types (this is distinct and different from the underlying type of the enum type), and the members inherited from `System.Enum` are available in any enum type. A boxing conversion exists from any enum type to `System.Enum`, and an unboxing conversion exists from `System.Enum` to any enum type.
>
> Note that `System.Enum` is not itself an *enum-type*. Rather, it is a *class-type* from which all *enum-type*s are derived. The type `System.Enum` inherits from the type `System.ValueType`, which, in turn, inherits from type `object`. At run-time, a value of type `System.Enum` can be null or a reference to a boxed value of any enum type.

Answer (score 0):

What is being asked here has not been entirely clear to me but I hope I got it now.

---

Given the code below:

```
void F(Object obj) {
  var isEnum obj is Enum;
  ...
}
```

What parts of the C# standard specifies that `isEnum` is true when `obj` is an instance of an enum type?

---

In *14.9.10 is operator* in the [C# Language Specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-334.pdf) there are five bullets describing how it is evaluated:

- The 1st bullet is about cases where `obj` has a more specific type than `System.Object`.
- The 2nd bullet is about nullable types.
- The 4th bullet is about generic types.
- The 5th bullet is when there are no matches and the `is` operator evaluates to false which we know it doesn't.

You would expect that the 3rd bullet applies to the code above. The 3rd bullet has four sub-bullets:

- The 1st sub-bullet applies when `obj` is null.
- The 2nd sub-bullet is about nullable types.
- The 4th sub-bullet is when there are no matches and the `is` operator evaluates to false which we know it doesn't.

You would expect the the 3rd sub-bullet applies:

> Otherwise, let R be the run-time type of the instance referenced by e. If R and T are the same type, if
>   R is a reference type and an implicit reference conversion from R to T exists, or if R is a value type
>   and T is an interface type that is implemented by R, the result is true.

However, there seems to be something specific about enum types missing here. Assuming `obj` is an instance of enum type `MyEnum` none of the clauses matches the code above:

- R and T are not the same type because R is `MyEnum` and T is `System.Enum`.
- R is `MyEnum` which is a value type (11.1.9) and not a reference type.
- T is `System.Enum` which is not an interface type.

I don't want to claim that there is an error in the specification, but after a detailed reading of 14.9.10 I'm unable to see how `is Enum` can evaluate to true given a boxed reference to an enum type.

Knowing that standards people in general are much smarter than I am I probably overlooked something, but even if I didn't this shouldn't stop you from using `is Enum` to test if a type is an enum. I'm sure that it is not an implementation detail that it can used like this.

Comment: @leppie: Your assertion is true, but I'm not talking about the type `Enum`. I'm talking about enumerations and `typeof(MyEnumeration).IsValueType` is `true` for any `MyEnumeration` you define by the keyword `enum`.

Comment: But the question asks about `Enum`, not `MyEnum`. Did I read the question wrong?

Comment: I read this question as "where in the spec is it explained why `X is Enum == true` when `X` is an enumeration?"

Comment: I don't deny that an enumeration value can be cast to Enum - I'm asking how the bulleted list immediately after the paragraph you quote from the spec covers this case. Similarly, I don't see how it covers the case `3 is object`.

Comment: In the ECMA version of the spec that you're using, the first bullet applies: there is a boxing conversion from any enum type to `Enum`.

Comment: @svick: The compile time type of `obj` is `System.Object` so I don't see how the first bullet applies. If I understand the first bullet correctly the criteria can be evaluated at compile time, not run-time.

Comment: @MartinLiversage, you're right, I overlooked that. It seems it really is a bug in that version of the spec. C# 4 spec has it correctly, though.

Answer (score 0):

Enum is an actual type where as class and struct are not.  Therefore, Enum can be used on the right-hand side where as class and struct cannot.

Comment: Not quite. You just contradicted yourself :)

Comment: interesting... well, hmm... where is Eric Lippert...  perhaps he can answer this question...

Comment: @leppie, there is no contradiction. `System.Enum` is an actual type. There is no such type for classes or structs. There is `System.ValueType`, but that is the base for all value types, not just structs.

Answer (score 0):

`Enum` is a reference type.

```
typeof(Enum).IsValueType => false
```

Interestingly,

```
typeof(ValueType).IsValueType => false
```

Comment: Yeah, I was just browsing the msdn site -> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.aspx.  Enum inherits from ValueType, which inherits from Object.  All of these are classes and therefore reference types.  Apparently, there were some issues with .IsClass in frameworks prior to .NET 4 -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1661913/typeofsystem-enum-isclass-false.

Comment: @CraigWilson: Interesting 'bug'. 99.9% of the time I am only interested in `.IsValueType` :)