# Convert String To Enum in a portable lib

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, enums

I'm trying to convert a string to an Enum, in a generic way, in a portable class Library

Targes are: .NET 4.5, Windows 8, Windows Phone 8.1, Windows Phone Silverlight 8

I have this string extension, which I've previous used in a Winform application. But in this library it does not compile. It is the line `if (!typeof(TEnum).IsEnum)` that doesn't work

```
public static class StringExtensions
{        

    public static TEnum? AsEnum<TEnum>(this string value) where TEnum : struct,  IComparable, IFormattable
    {
        if (!typeof(TEnum).IsEnum)
            throw new ArgumentException("TEnum must be an enumerated type");

        TEnum result;
        if (Enum.TryParse(value, true, out result))
            return result;

        return null;
    }
 }
```

So my question is: In the given context how do I test for a given type is an enum?

Comment: Please define "doesn't work".

Comment: Can it be helpful? Like this: typeof(TEnum) is Enum. Source: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2918826/1380428

Comment: Weird, the [documentation for `Type.IsEnum`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isenum%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) specifies it as available in the portable library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using [`GetTypeInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.introspectionextensions.gettypeinfo%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
using System.Reflection; // to get the extension method for GetTypeInfo()    

if(typeof(TEnum).GetTypeInfo().IsEnum)
  // whatever
```

Comment: Thank you for your helt 

I'd go with this solution because it was the closest to what I'd had allready.

Answer (score 3):

If `Type.IsEnum` isn't supported, you could always use:

```
if (typeof(TEnum).BaseType != typeof(Enum))
```

(Assuming `BaseType` is available, of course.)

Comment: Is `IsEnum` implemented this way?

Comment: @RicoSuter: No idea. I suspect there's a more efficient way of doing it internally, but this should work.